# Задача о рюкзаке

Tags: pascal

Как восстановить список предметов, которые необходимо взять?
Эта задача ДП.

Comment: кхм, взять и вывести.

Comment: [Задача о ранце с возможностью единичного выбора предмета](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_3).

Comment: Как просчитать максимальный вес я знаю, как востановить по этой матрице какие надо брать вещи?

Comment: Я так понял что при наборе предметов он хочет восстанавливать что он взял же в рюкзак,если так то вам сюда (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-items-01-knapsack/)

Answer (score 3):

```
writeln('предметы, которые необходимо взять');
```

В чем вопрос?

Comment: Эта задача Динамического программирования.